# Are Mule ESB object stores persistent across redeploys?

Tags: mule, esb

Mule ESB CE supports object stores, which can be set to persistent. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056997/how-to-share-data-between-mule-apps-dont-use-databaseusing-object-store) I know also, that the stores are application-specific if defined in the application XMLs.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find any information if any data will be lost when:

1. Mule is restarted
2. Mule is killed
3. The application is re-deployed

I'm almost sure that (1) has no impact on the data. I suppose that the object store is also kill-agnostic. What about application being redeployed? I think there are 2 scenarios here:

1. Object store is defined on app-level
2. Object store is defined on domain-level

Am I right that in the 1st scenario data will be lost, while the latter will retain the data across application redeploys?

I'm working on Mule 3.5.0 CE.

Any help & references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1,2 and 3 data should be persistent and available upon restart/redeploy etc. The only issue is changing the application name since object stores use the application name as part of the persisted storage information, so if you want the data to be available across redeploys, the newly deployed application must have the same name as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

In no cases data will be lost from the queue until it's tried (depends upon configuration) and it goes to DLQ.